# Select previous and next record in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a script that selects the previous and next post via MySQL. This works fine.

But I want at the first post **not** showing the previous post, because there is no post before.
The same at the last post, because there is no post after.

SELECT **PREVIOUS** POST:

```
<?php
$stmt = $db->query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID - 1 FROM posts) LIMIT 1");
while ($row = $stmt->fetch())
{
echo $row['post'];
}
?>
```

SELECT **NEXT** POST

```
<?php
$stmt = $db->query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID + 1 FROM posts) LIMIT 1");
while ($row = $stmt->fetch())
{
echo $row['post'];
}
?>
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you use the MAX clause, as in `select max(id-1), 0` in your sub-clause? Substitute something else for zero perhaps, and I don't know how you'd deal with the last post unless you already know the last ID and could use it in "min". Normally a "previous" or "next" link or button would contain the actual ID rather than calculating it this way - how will you deal with deleted posts when the ID is missing?

Comment: If you include `ORDER BY id` you could use `LIMIT 3` to get the set of records.  Just need to work out how to get the previous ID.

Comment: you want to implement pagination kind of feature, if yes then you need to use 3 things `ORDER BY id DESC`, `LIMIT 3` and `OFFSET 1`.

Comment: Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)